# i always getting error on migration , what can i do for this kind of error

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, migration

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table def
inition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
(SQL: create table `students` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment pr
imary key, `student_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `
stuent_name` varchar(50) not null, `student_email` varchar(50) not null, `s
tudent_username` varchar(50) not null, `student_phone` varchar(50) not null
, `student_photo` text not null, `student_sex` varchar(191) not null, `stud
ent_status` varchar(191) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at
` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
```

**i dont know what happen , this problem is happen when i try to migrate**

Comment: post your schema definition

Comment: php artisan migrate

Comment: not that, post schema definition of the code in your `App\database\migrations\`

Comment: Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->increments('student_id');
            $table->string('stuent_name', 50);
            $table->string('student_email',50);
            $table->string('student_username',50);
            $table->string('student_phone',50);
            $table->text('student_photo');
            $table->string('student_sex');
            $table->string('student_status');
            $table->timestamps();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two auto_increment key `id` and `studuent_id`. You can only set one as the auto increment key.

Comment: if i have id and another student_id on the same table then what can i do ??

Comment: @prakashpokhrel I think you can remove column id then keep the student_id. Or you can manually incremet id.

Comment: @prakashpokhrel glad it helps